# What's the meaning of "[" and ")" in semver (Semantic versioning) which is used in SCA Analysis

Tags: version-control, versioning, semantic-versioning, sca

I already spent a week with semver, and got the basics, i'm not able to understand what's the meaning of "[" and ")" in semver. I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/semver to compare versions in my project.

However, I can see some lib's versions from Snyk's database look like:

```
[2.0-beta9,2.3.1) [2.4,2.12.2) [2.13.0,2.15.0)
```

Here what's the meaning of "[" and ")", most of the time values are something like

```
<=2.0.1
<2.1.1
=2.32.2
```

Can someone help me with this, please?

This is the link to public database - https://security.snyk.io/vuln/SNYK-JAVA-ORGAPACHELOGGINGLOG4J-2314720

[image]

Comment: They're **not** in [semver](https://semver.org/) (which defines no syntax for _ranges_, only _versions_).